# Upgraded MFC application still looks old

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-6

I have an MFC application written with VC6.  I have upgraded it to VS2015 and it builds and runs. The application is a main exe with many DLL's that have dialogs in them.

However the application still *looks* like it is built with VC6.  None of the GUI components have the Windows 7 look and feel, they all still look old style.

How can I make my existing application look more modern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should at least add this line to your project, for example add it to `stdafx.h`

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Or add the following to your manifest file:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

See also [Enabling Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It gets more complicated for owner draw controls. See this reference:
[Using Visual Styles with Custom and Owner-Drawn Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For ListView and TreeView controls, you can call this function for a more modern look (although it doesn't make any difference in Windows 10)

```
SetWindowTheme(m_ListView.m_hWnd, L"Explorer", NULL);
SetWindowTheme(m_TreeView.m_hWnd, L"Explorer", NULL);
```

<sub>* *`#pragma comment` is Visual Studio specific. For other compilers you need to modify the manifest file*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your linker setting `ALLOWISOLATION` is set to 'Yes' otherwise the manifest is not even considered.