# Why are my MFC dialogs showing different styles in Visual Studio and at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

I've recently inherited an old MFC application and am puzzled by differences in how its dialogs are styled in different places.

When I open the .RC file and look at the dialogs in Visual Studio they look significantly different than they do at runtime.  Most notably, dialog frame and button borders both have a rounded style and the buttons have a gradient applied.  When I run the application they have a square/flat style.  I'd prefer the style shown in the designer; but don't know where/why it's not being used at runtime.

The screenshot on the left is from the VS designer.  The one on the right is what I'm seeing when I run the application itself.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any code like this: `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"", L"");` in you `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog`? Where `hwnd` is `GetDlgItem(IDOK)->m_hWnd` etc.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani No calls to `SetWindowTheme()` at all; and there doesn't appear to be any boilerplate shared between the various `OnInitDialog()` methods.

Comment: Okay, the dialog designer shows the so-called "New Look" with "Visual Style" enabled. But when you run the program this new look is not enabled. You can tell the program to enable the new look. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728815 In your case you probably don't want the new look, so everything is fine! But if you do want the new look, then remove the "client edge" flag from the buttons or use `SetWindowTheme` to exclude some controls from having the new look.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That did the trick; and I did notice changing client edge made them look better in the designer when I was fiddling with anything that looked like it might be relevant (I didn't change it immediately since I wanted to resolve the design/run time discrepancy first).  Did you misread my question (I do prefer the new look), or is there something problematic with it that is recommended to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I misread your question. You can enable the new look with no problem.