# Progress bar colour changes when mfc dialog based project is set to multibyte character set

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created MFC dialog based project and by default character set is set to unicode character set. when i change to multibyte character set the progress bar color changes(attached images). The project which I am working in is set to multibyte character set,I would like to get progress bar like aero themed. Any help is appreciated.

[set to unicode character set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGtWq.png)

[image]

[set to multibyte character set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BirGZ.png)

[image]

Comment: This is a weird behavior in Visual Studio 2008, and maybe other versions. You can fix it by enable Visual Styles. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728815/upgraded-mfc-application-still-looks-old/32729776#32729776) on how to enable Visual Styles (add `#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency ...` ) to one of your *.cpp files. I would recommend just using Unicode. Please post your version of Visual Studio, it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks barmak. I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: (add #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency ... )  solved issue. The whole project needs to be converted to unicode, is there any easy way to convert it?