# How to change border color of a listview

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I have created a list view using win32 api.

```
InitCommonControls();
HWND hwndList1 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"", WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS |  LVS_ICON  | LV_VIEW_TILE |  LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | WS_BORDER | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | ES_LEFT , 10, 10, 300, 190, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 

SendMessageW( hwndList1,
            LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
            LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT ,
            LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT );



CreateItem(hwndList1 , (char*)L"fault RS458");
CreateItem(hwndList1 , (char*)L"fault RS455");
CreateColumn(hwndList1 , 0 , (char*)L"Insert column" , 300);
```

I see a black border around the list view. How can i change its color?

Comment: Try removing `WS_BORDER ` style. Also see MS's example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-list-view-control

Comment: @Jesper Juhl i created it using win32 api...edited my question

Comment: @ Richard Critten By removing `WS_BORDER` border are removed

Comment: I think WS_BORDER would be using system colors, so easiest way to override it is to subclass and handle WM_NCPAINT yourself.

Comment: @bunglehead Thanks...Please can you tell me how to subclass? You mean i have to create a class for the list view?

Comment: @Code-Lover basically you create a window, and override its window procedure with your own that handles WM_NCPAINT is any way you want. You can certainly create a new class just for that, but it's not necessary.

Comment: BTW, you are using incorrect style flags. The `LV_VIEW_TILE` can only be set by sending a `LVM_SETVIEW` message. For the `LVS_EX_*` flags you have to send `LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE`.  Finally, `ES_LEFT` is not related to listview at all, it belongs to the edit control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass the window using [SetWindowSubclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) (requires comctl32.lib) and handle [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint) to paint the non-client area of the control as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewProc(HWND hwnd, 
    UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
        OffsetRect(&rc, -rc.left, -rc.top);
        auto hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
        auto hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        auto oldpen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);//draw red frame
        SelectObject(hdc, oldpen);
        DeleteObject(oldpen);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        //*** EDIT
        //documentation says we should return 0
        //but that causes problem with vertical scrollbar
        //maybe we should break for this subclass case

        break; //not return 0!
    }

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ListViewProc, 0);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
...
HWND hwndList1 = CreateWindow(...); 
SetWindowSubclass(hwndList1, ListViewProc, 0, NULL);
```

<sub>Side note, `(char*)L"text"` doesn't make sense. Either use ANSI (`(char*)"text"`) or Unicode (`(wchar_t*)L"text"`, recommended). You can change `CreateItem` to accept `const wchar_t*`, then cast to `(wchar_t*)` for `LVITEM` at the last step to avoid errors.</sub>

Edit
`WM_NCPAINT` will break, not return zero.

Comment: Please can you tell me for removing the 3d border from the header what messages and inside what proc should  i handle?Thanks

Comment: You should edit the question and add some pictures to show what you want. The listview control has its own header control, you may have to subclass that control. By the way, do you have the "Modern UI" enabled? Look at this post for [enabling visual styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729776/4603670)

Comment: It looks like you have the default settings. All of your controls have the old 3-D look, which dates back to 1990s. You need to enable Visual Styles. Then your listview, buttons, checkboxes, etc. will look like the ones in Windows Explorer. See the earlier comment. Do you use Visual Studio? If not, you have to include a manifest file in your `*.rc` resource file `1 24 "myapplication.exe.manifest"`

Comment: When i enable visual style, the 3d border is removed but background color and text color that i have specified in custom draw no longer is applied.Is there a way to change background and text color of the header when uses visual styles ?

Comment: Use `HWND hHeader = ListView_GetHeader(hListView)` to get the header control. Use `SetWindowTheme(hHeader, L"", L"");` if you want to revert back old-3d look for individual controls. Then use "owner draw" (not "custom draw") to repaint. I showed how to use "custom draw" in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647001/4603670) I am confused about where you are at. You should post a new question.

Comment: You should return 0 to show that you completely handled the message.