# How to set header width equal to its list view control width when list view is resized?

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I want to set width of header in a list view to width of its list view control when it is resized using win32 api.So i use `ListView_SetColumnWidth()` to set its width equal to its control's width but it does not work.

This is The code inside `WinMain()`:

```
InitCommonControls();
hwndList1 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL, 10 , 10 , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 

//Sub classing the list control
SetWindowSubclass(hwndList1 ,ListProc,0 ,NULL);

SendMessage(hwndList1,LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
hHeader1=ListView_GetHeader(hwndList1);

GetClientRect(hwndList1 , &rect1);
CreateColumn(hwndList1 , 0 , (char*)L"MASTER" , rect1.right );

//enable arrows
EnableScrollBar(hwndList1 , SB_VERT , ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);

//scroll down
SendMessage(hwndList1, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0L);
```

This is `ListProc()`:

```
//the list proc
LRESULT CALLBACK ListProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp,UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR ){
switch(msg)
{
    case WM_NOTIFY :
     if (((LPNMHDR) lp)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
     {

         LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpcd = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lp;
         switch(lpcd->dwDrawStage)
         {
            case CDDS_PREPAINT :
                return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            {

                    SetBkColor(lpcd->hdc, RGB(0, 135, 234));
                    SetTextColor(lpcd->hdc, RGB(255, 255, 245));
                return CDRF_NEWFONT;
            }
                break;
        }
    }

break;

    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
     RECT rc;
     GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
     OffsetRect(&rc, -rc.left, -rc.top);
     auto hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
     auto hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(201, 201, 201));
     auto oldpen = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
     SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
     Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
     SelectObject(hdc, oldpen);
     DeleteObject(oldpen);
     ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
     return 0;
    }

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
     RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ListProc, 0);
     break;
 }

 return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
  }
```

And the following code is `WndProc()` for parent window procedure:

```
//The window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd , UINT msg , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam){
  switch(msg){
   case WM_SIZE:{
    int nHeight , nWidth;

    width =(int)((nWidth /2) * 0.8);
    height =(int)((nHeight/2) * 0.7);

    if( wParam == SIZE_RESTORED ){ 

     SetWindowPos(hwndList1, 0 , 10, 10 , width, height,SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE); 

    RECT Rc;
    GetClientRect(hwndList1, &Rc);
    ListView_SetColumnWidth(hwndList1, 0, Rc.right - Rc.left);
    }

    else if ( wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED )
     {
        SetWindowPos(hwndList1, 0 , 20, 20, width, height,0); 
        RECT Rc;
        GetClientRect(hwndList1, &Rc);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(hwndList1, 0, Rc.right - Rc.left);//
     } 
    }
    break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
            LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
            switch(lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                    return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:

                    if (((int)lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec%2)==0) {
                        lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(0,0,0);
                        lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(255, 255, 255);
                    } else {
                        lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(0,0,0);
                        lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(255,255,255);
                    }
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

            }

    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND: 
     switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE , 0 , 0);
            break;
        case ID_ABOUT:
        {
          int ret=DialogBox( GetModuleHandle(NULL) , MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ABOUT) , hwnd , AboutDlgProc );

        }
        break;
     }
     break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
     DestroyWindow( hwnd );
     break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
     PostQuitMessage(0);
     break;

    default:
     return DefWindowProc( hwnd , msg , wParam , lParam );
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

What am i missing? Is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: _"but it does not work."_ isn't a concise problem description. Also post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: part of WndProc() of what window ? parent of list view ? but where you resize list view first ? or you subclass list view and this is from subclass proc ?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I updated

Comment: @RbMm That is parent window procedure...I updated

Comment: the `WM_NOTIFY`, `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is send to parent window, not to window itself. so code for handle it in `ListProc`, `HeaderProc` senseless. unclear for what you at all subclass - not need in your case. why you have 2 different if for `SIZE_RESTORED` and `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` while have the same code for both ?

Comment: @RbMm Yes `HeaderProc`  was totally senseless i removed.I use `ListProc` for header color.I have 2 condition for `SIZE_RESTORED` and `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` because i change top and left coordinates but i removed them for being simple here thanks for hints i edited that

Comment: you need have single case for `SIZE_RESTORED` and `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` but not 2 duplicated piece of code. and **print** (say with `DbgPrint` )all values from `WM_SIZE` case, result of `ListView_SetColumnWidth` (may be for debug call after it `ListView_GetColumnWidth`) - this is how this problem researched

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetClientRect` to find the inner rectangle for the control. Example:

```
case WM_SIZE:
{
    //resize the listview control first
    //calculate width/height
    SetWindowPos(hwndList1, NULL, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE);

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwndList1, &rc);
    ListView_SetColumnWidth(hwndList1, 0, rc.right - rc.left);//rc.left is zero
    break;
}
```

The client rectangle can be a bit smaller than the window rectangle.

You can use width/height to set the size of listview control using `SetWindowPos` or `MoveWindow`. This will correspond to `GetWindowRect`. But you want the client rectangle for column width.

You can also subclass the listview control and respond to `WM_SIZE` in `listview_proc`.

`WM_SIZE` is sent when the user resizes the main window. It is not triggered by default when the window is first opened. You may have to call `ListView_SetColumnWidth` when the window is first initialized.

---

Also note, you cannot handle custom draw inside `ListProc`. You must remove `WM_NOTIFY` section from `ListProc`, add it to `WndProc` only.

Suggested edit:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        int nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
        int nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
        int width = (int)((nWidth / 2) * 0.8);
        int height = (int)((nHeight / 2) * 0.7);
        SetWindowPos(hwndList1, 0, 20, 20, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER);
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwndList1, &rc);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(hwndList1, 0, rc.right - rc.left);
    }
    break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
        {
            LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
            switch(lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
            {
            case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(255, 255, 0);
                return CDRF_NEWFONT;
            }
        }
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work when i maximize the parent window,list view control is wider than header.I updated my codes in question please can you take a look at that?

Comment: It seems you forgot to initialize `nWidth` and `nHeight` in your second version of the code. This will cause undefined behavior. It's recommended to set compiler's warning level to 4 or higher. Make sure you address all compiler warnings, such as uninitialized variables. Also remove custom draw from `ListProc`

Comment: @Barmak: Just curious, is there information somewhere about the motivation for the removal of custom draw, or how an alternative implementation should go? Thanks. :)

Comment: @LaurieStearn The question was about resizing header, it was not related to custom draw, so I suggested removing custom draw portion in order to simplify the issue. Otherwise using custom draw in ListView control is fine.