# Split button control is disappear on MFC dialog

Tags: mfc, split-button

I am almost new in MFC.
I just drag and drop a new split button control from the toolbox to a dialog.
Then I changed the button's caption. (Prefer the attached img)
I tried to run the application. The new button is disappeared.
When I moved a mouse over the button position and left mouse click. A tiny rectangle look likes
a checkbox is shown.

What was going wrong with the properties parameter setting?
May I missed something? Why the new split button is not shown?

More, OnBnClickedSplit1() is not implemented yet.
Another button are still shown normally.
[image]

```cpp
// MFCApplication5Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication5.h"
#include "MFCApplication5Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CMFCApplication5Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication5Dlg::CMFCApplication5Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication5Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication5Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_SPLIT1, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedSplit1)
    ON_NOTIFY(BCN_DROPDOWN, IDC_SPLIT1, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnDropDownSplit1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication5Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CString StrTmp;
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}


void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
}


void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedSplit1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}


void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnDropDownSplit1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMBCDROPDOWN pDropDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMBCDROPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    *pResult = 0;
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: Common issue: Trying to use MFC without understanding the Windows API. Please show a [mcve]. That should include the relevant section of your resource script. If you don't know what a resource script is, consider getting your hands on a copy of Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: *"... should include the relevant section of your resource script. If you don't know what a resource script is ..."*

Comment: You have to enable Visual Styles, otherwise new windows controls won't work. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729776/4603670) I am not sure where the check box is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do following:

1. Add this at the beginning of your `CMFCApplication5App::InitInstance()` function if it's not already somewhere in your code:

---

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);
```

2. Add this to one of your .h files, for example to `stdafx.h`

---

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

---

But the problem could be something else. To be sure you need to show us the relevant section of your .rc file.

Comment: This solution was OK for me. However, I still wonder why and what is the root cause? Some common control DLL are not loaded,right?

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)