# CPropertySheet - removing frame

Tags: mfc, propertysheet

Iam trying to remove the frame of my CPropertySheet.
I googled a lot in the last days, but couldnt find a solution.

i thought it would work with:

```
ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0,0);
ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, 0, 0);
```

but it doesnt^^

here is a picture
https://ibb.co/R7b0tdD

i want to remove this 3D border

Comment: I don't think property sheet has `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` flag. Maybe you have the old-style dialogbox + propertysheet and you want the modern look?

Comment: https://ibb.co/R7b0tdD
it looks like this and i want to remove this 3D border

Comment: I can't tell anything by that picture. Make sure you have enabled Visual Styles https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729776/4603670

Comment: `CMFCPropertySheet` is more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine, but try removing all border/frame styles but WS_BORDER and make sure to remove WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE style. This is just a guess but I would start with the above steps.